# How to I find the difference in days between customers each visit

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe with multiple transactions of each customer

```
ID   Date of visit
123 08/09/2013
123 01/02/2014
123 08/08/2014
123 12/03/2017
abd 01/09/2016
```

I want to aggregate the record in such a way that my dataframe looks like

```
ID   First visit   Second visit   Third visit
123 08/09/2013     01/02/2014    08/08/2014
```

Is it possible do like this? I have one million records wit 30,000 customer. How do I approach the problem

Comment: See Q10 in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe), exchange `index` and `columns`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
new_df=df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['Date_of_visit'].reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
new_df.columns=  ['Visit_'+str(key+1) for key in new_df.columns]
print(new_df)
```

---

```
        Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4
ID                                                 
123  08/09/2013  01/02/2014  08/08/2014  12/03/2017
abd  01/09/2016         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to concat nth(i)

[image]